# wso2 using the response and conditional

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Is it possible to use the json from a response as a property and then use that to make a conditional statement? I looked into conditional router and sequence to make this happen but I don't know how to get the response and put it in a property mediator or just use it for conditional router.

example I have this response

```
{
    "fruit": "apple"
}
```

and then I want to check if the key fruit is an apple.

```
if (response.fruit == "apple") {
    callMediator();
} else {
    callOtherMediator();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set to property:

```
<property name="fruit" expression="//fruit"/>
```

To check, use [Filter Mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Filter+Mediator).

```
<filter source="$ctx:fruit" regex="apple">
      <then>
          <send/>
      </then>
      <else>
          <drop/>
      </else>
</filter>
```